# Bash syntax: if [ ! -f \"{}\" ]; then exit 1; fi'

Tags: bash, airflow

I'm reading this bash command in a Bash Operator for Apache Airflow and I couldn't really understand it despite some Googling attempt.

```
if [ ! -f \"{}\" ]; then exit 1; fi
```

in this code chunk:

```
check_file_existence =  BashOperator(
    task_id='check_file_existence',
    bash_command='if [ ! -f \"{}\" ]; then exit 1; fi'.format(input_file))
```

Could you help me explaining this bash command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `format()` method will replace `{}` with the value of `input_file`. If the value of `input_file` is `somefile.txt`, the shell command will become

```
if [ ! -f "somefile.txt" ]; then exit 1; fi
```

This will exit with a non-zero status code, indicating an error, if the file doesn't exist.

The `if` statement isn't really needed, since the `[` or `test` command itself works the same way. It can be simplified to

```
check_file_existence =  BashOperator(
    task_id='check_file_existence',
    bash_command='test -f \"{}\"'.format(input_file))
```